# My CSS background won't show

Tags: html, css

I have checked and double checked the syntax, but I'm unsure why my CSS background won't load:

```
 body { 
  font-family: cursive,serif; 
  background: url("../images/background.jpeg") no-repeat center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**Folder Structure**

```
--index.html
--style.css
--images
  |____ background.jpeg
```

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing the image correctly? `"../images/background.jpeg"` most likely is pointed to the wrong place.

Comment: You are selecting ".body" as a class. Is it in fact a class or were you ment to select or "body" as a html tag?

Comment: @HunterTurner I am using Brackets and it is showing me a preview of the image. it is referenced correctly. the image "background.jpeg" is in a folder "images"

Comment: @MateuszJuruś although you were correct. I have to select body as a html tag it is still not showing.

Comment: Where is this CSS code? is it in an HTML file or a referenced CSS file? If it is the later, in what folder do you have the CSS file?

Comment: @RacilHilan it is the latter. the CSS file is in the same folder as the html file. There is a subfolders for images.

Comment: You need to mention that in the question. Are the HTML and CSS files in the root folder? I added the file structure to your question, so update it if it is incorrect.

Comment: try `background-image` to `background` updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/egs6x22j/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues in your CSS:

- `.body` is used to select elements with `body` class (e.g. `<div class="body"></div>`). If you actually want to add the CSS to the `<body>`, remove the dot at the beginning.
- The image is in the `image` subfolder of your HTML file, and the CSS file is in the root folder. You can use `url("images/background.jpeg")`.

Here is the CSS with the above suggestions:

```
body {
  font-family: cursive, serif;
  background: url("images/background.jpeg") no-repeat center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```